# How to ensure that windows opened from the Dock open in the current Space/Desktop

Tags: macos, applescript, desktop, spaces, mission-control

A Mail window was in the Dock, and I clicked on it to restore it to my current Desktop.  Instead of opening where I can see it, it went to some other Desktop, presumably the one it was in when it was minimized.

I use different Desktops for different projects, where one Desktop may have multiple browser windows, multiple text editors, etc., so I've disabled the default setting of "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application", because that seems to only make sense if you use an approach of one Space per Application, which makes no sense for me.  As far as I can tell this is the only setting I'm using that may be relevant to this problem, but I really really don't want to have OS X forcing me to constantly switch spaces and force me into a one-space-per-app model.

[image: Mission Control settings]

Is there some way to make the window I restore (de-minimize) appear in *my current Space/Desktop*?  It could be

- a hidden preference that I set with `defaults write`;
- an AppleScript that I have to trigger after restoring the window, to move it to my current Space/Desktop;
- some utility application meant to handle this problem
- some other workaround or solution I hadn't thought of.

(An AppleScript would probably be the least desirable approach, but it could be triggered with Alfred, QuicKeys, or BetterTouchTool, etc.)

It might also be worth mentioning that I'm using Yosemite because of problems between El Capitan and TotalSpaces2, but I'd like to know if upgrading solves this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> "click" on the minimized window in the dock, and it will restore (de-minimize) in the current workspace, regardless of which space it was on when it was minimized.

Comment: doesn't work if "Minimize windows into application icon" setting is enabled, but still upvoting this one.

Comment: Is there any way to make this the default?  I'd rather use `command` to put the window into "the background" (i.e. another space), much like command-clicking on a link puts the link into a background tab in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly this helps your situation:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO; killall Dock
```

Comment: will this make it open in my current space, or just avoid switching spaces when it is restored?

Comment: somehow yes. It does not auto change to the space the window is opened again, which helps staying in context. you then can use the context menu in the dock to bring the window to this space.

Comment: Unfortunately it has a side effect.  Now if I (e.g.) select a window from the Window menu, I do not switch to the space of that window.

Comment: Do I need to logout/login again? This doesn't work on macOS Catalina

Comment: Doesn't work in Catalina for me either

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working with some help from koekeishiya's [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai).

First we disable the workspaces swoosh as @mahal tertin mentioned:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO; killall Dock
```

Then we add this bit of code to our `.yabairc` file:

```
yabai_query_current_space="\$(yabai -m query --spaces --space | jq '.index' )"
yabai -m signal --add event=window_deminimized action="yabai -m window $YABAI_WINDOW_ID --space $yabai_query_current_space"
```

Effectively, this instructs yabai to send a deminimizing window to the current space when it receives a deminimize event.

Depends on having `yabai` and `jq` installed.

ref: https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/blob/master/doc/yabai.asciidoc#signal

Comment: What's the location of the `.yabairc` _file_?

Comment: I have mine in my $HOME directory. https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/wiki/Configuration#configuration-file

Comment: I should also mention that if you don't want all the other cool features of yabai you can put `yabai -m config layout float` in your `.yabairc` file to basically disable the window tiling features.

Comment: great find! but "System Integrity Protection needs to be (partially) disabled for yabai to inject a scripting addition into Dock.app" scares me a little 

Comment: I'm actually using it without the scripting addition! Most of the yabai features work without it. I'm on a work computer so got to have everything secure.

Comment: @pete-may: which features work, and which features fail without the scripting addition?  thanks!

Comment: @iconoclast no idea! I've never turned on scripting addition so I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the application is set to "Assign To All Desktops" when you second-click on the icon and go to "Options"

[image]

[This writeup](https://www.macrumors.com/2011/07/21/lion-assigning-apps-to-all-desktops-in-mission-control/) eliminated years of frustration. :)

Comment: If I were to do that for all apps, it would literally make Desktops completely useless.  So that's clearly not a solution.  (The whole point of Desktops is to have _different windows_ on each Desktop.   Without that, they have exactly zero purpose.)

Comment: Yes. Use a combination of all three settings.